# SUM and group by with parent_id

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have tables:

**Categories**

```
+----+-----------+---------------+
| id | parent_id | name          |
+----+-----------+---------------+
|  1 |      NULL | Dong ho nam   |
|  2 |         1 | dong ho nam 1 |
|  3 |         1 | dong ho nam 2 |
|  4 |         1 | dong ho nam 3 |
|  5 |         1 | dong ho nam 4 |
|  6 |      NULL | Dong ho nu    |
|  7 |         6 | Dong ho nu 1  |
|  8 |         6 | Dong ho nu 2  |
|  9 |         6 | Dong ho nu 3  |
+----+-----------+---------------+
```

and table **Products**:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+
| id | category_id | quantity      |
+----+-------------+---------------+
|  1 |         6   | 10            |
|  2 |         3   | 2             |
|  3 |         3   | 4             |
|  4 |         2   | 12            |
|  5 |         4   | 6             |
|  6 |         2   | 0             |
|  7 |         6   | 8             |
|  8 |         8   | 22            |
|  9 |         9   | 4             |
+----+-------------+---------------+
```

I want to select category, sum(quantity)
// (all quantity of product belong to category and category.parent_id = null)

**Result** :

```
+----+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| id | parent_id | name          | quantity  |
+----+-----------+---------------+-----------+
|  1 |      NULL | Dong ho nam   |     24    |
|  6 |      NULL | Dong ho nu    |     44    |
+----+-----------+---------------+-----------+
```

How to use sql query (or rails ) can achieve above result.
 tks.

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of parent/child relationships?  If not, since `mysql` doesn't support recursive ctes, this will be more difficult and require `dynamic sql`... Or you might be able to do this with `user-defined variables` and a subquery.

Comment: @sgeddes : i edit data table Categories. 
ex:  maximum number of parent/child  relationships = 2
can you write a sql ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate both on the parent and the child.  Something like this should be close:

```
select c.id, p.quantity + coalesce(sum(p2.quantity),0) 
from categories c
    join (
        select category_id, sum(quantity) quantity
        from products 
        group by category_id) p on c.id = p.category_id 
    left join categories c2 on c.id = c2.parent_id
    left join products p2 on c2.id = p2.category_id
where c.parent_id is null
group by c.id
```